# using the .val attr in jquery

Tags: jquery

Basically when i type something in the textarea, i can change the font either by inputting a size in a input box with id font_size  or clicking the 64px button, once the font changes and i click done, i appended the value of what's in the textarea to the image in the div with an id image_conv but the problem here is that it doesn't take the formatted value of the text in the textarea to the div, i want the output in the div to be the formatted text value. Does anyone know how i can solve this?
Many thanks in advance.
ps: i uploaded the backgroung image of the text area on image shack so everyone could use it, i don't know if it works though cos i haven't tried it :)

```
 <html>  
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
     function sixty_four() {
        var text_input = $('#textarea');
        text_input.css("font-size", "64px");
       }
     function append_font() {
       var text_input = $('#textarea');
       var font = $('#font_size').val();
        text_input.css("font-size", font + "px");
       }
      function text_manual() { 
      var text_value = $('#textarea').val();
      $('#image_conv').append(text_value);
      $('#image_conv').fadeIn('slow');
      }
    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
    #textarea {
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    resize: none;
    }

    #image_conv {
        background: url(http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/97/sliverc.png/) no-repeat left top;
        border: 3px solid #000;
        height:300px;
        width:300px;
    }


    </style>
    </head>

    <body>

    <textarea id="textarea"> </textarea><br/><br/>
    Font size:<input type="text" id="font_size"/><input type="button" id="font_size" value="Append Font" onClick="append_font()"/> 
    <input type="button" id="64px" value="64px" onClick="sixty_four()" /><br/><br/>
    <input type="button" id="manual_text" value="Done" onClick="text_manual()"/> 
    <div id="image_conv" >
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What do you actually want to be formatted: The `<textarea>` or the `div#image_conv`?

Comment: Sorry if i wasn't clear, i meant the formatted value of the text in the textarea. So basically when i type in the textarea and i click on the 64px button it formats the text in the textarea to 64px and then when i click done it appends the value of what's in the textarea to the div. But it doesn't append the formatted value from the textarea it just appends it as a normal text with its default value.

Comment: Do you need [something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/SCBpM/)?

Comment: @TommyD.Adey Great, I am posting it as an answer, so you can accept it to mark this question resolved.

Comment: btw do you know how i can disable scrolling effect from a textarea, lets say to make the text area cut out characters that don't fit the original box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you should do it:

```
$('#sixty_four').click(function(){
    $('#textarea').css('font-size', '64px');
});
$('#font_size_btn').click(function() {
    $('#textarea').css('font-size', $('#font_size').val() + 'px');
});
$('#manual_text').click(function(){ 
    var $textarea = $('#textarea');
    $('#image_conv')
        .html($textarea.val())
        .css('font-size', $textarea.css('font-size'))
        .fadeIn('slow');
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/SCBpM/)

Comment: Thanks again,btw do you know how i can disable scrolling effect from a textarea, lets say to make the text area cut out characters that don't fit the original box?

Comment: @TommyD.Adey In your CSS use `overflow:hidden;` for the `textarea` element.

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you again but look at this http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/SCBpM/ if you type in a long text and click the 64px button then click done, the text appended unto the div doesn't stay in the div, is there a way to correct this?

Comment: @TommyD.Adey Add `overflow:hidden` to `#image_conv`. Try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Shef/zAF2D/).

Comment: Thanks very much you've been a great help, i wish i could give you 100   ups lol thanks again..

Answer (score 0):

The text in the textarea isn't formatted, it's the textarea element that is.

If you want to display the text from the textarea in another element with the same style as in the textarea, you have to apply the same style to the element as the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you would like to have the same font size in the div as you have set for the textarea?

Couldnt you just include the img_div in your js like this:

```
function sixty_four() {
    var text_input = $('#textarea');
    var img_div = $('#image_conv');
    text_input.css("font-size", "64px");
    img_div.css("font-size", "64px");
}

function append_font() {
    var text_input = $('#textarea');
    var img_div = $('#image_conv');
    var font = $('#font_size').val();
    text_input.css("font-size", font + "px");
    img_div.css("font-size", font + "px");
}

function text_manual() { 
    var text_value = $('#textarea').val();
    $('#image_conv').append(text_value);
    $('#image_conv').fadeIn('slow');
}
```

I am not sure if I understood your question correctly, so I might be completly wrong here...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/krdAy/